# Como solucionar Unexpected end of JSON input usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Tenho uma API em Java que autentica um usuário com base no email e senha do mesmo utilizando o JWT.

Estou tentando consumir esta API com jQuery.

Ao rodar o seguinte método, a requisição cai no error com o seguinte erro "Unexpected end of JSON input" mas na página, o código da requisição é 200.

Alguém saberia me ajudar?

[link para api](https://github.com/LuLiveira/spring-boot-ionic)

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $("#btn-login").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
            data: JSON.stringify(dados),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            responseType: 'text',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            success: function(result, status, request) {
                //Note que o result geralmente exibe ou como Object ou Document dependendo do retorno. Não tenho certeza devido a ser json - que não sou muito familiarizado
                alert("Estado atual---\n" + status + "\nResultado: " + result);
                //Abaixo está listando os header do conteudo que você requisitou, só para confirmar se você setou os header e dataType corretos
                alert("Informações da requisição: \n" + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
                confirmationValue = result; //Repassa o retorno da requisição para teste futuro
            },
            error: function(request, status, erro) {
                alert("Problema ocorrido: " + status + "\nDescição: " + erro);
                //Abaixo está listando os header do conteudo que você requisitou, só para confirmar se você setou os header e dataType corretos
                alert("Informações da requisição: \n" + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `dados` em `JSON.stringify(dados)` seria o q? No código não tem essa variável.

Comment: Ou então, provavelmente, o retorno do Ajax não é um JSON válido.

Comment: dados é email e senha que estou enviando para validar